# Dependent object in the stored procedure is dropped and recreated again

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I am trying to test a scenario when the dependent object in a stored procedure is dropped and recreated again.

I need a way to re-compile the stored procedure, without recreating it.

```sql
CREATE TABLE t1
(
    c1 int
)

CREATE PROCEDURE tst_Proc
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO t1 
    VALUES (1)
END

DROP TABLE t1

CREATE TABLE t1
(
    c1 int
)
```

Now the `tst_Proc` will be in invalid state, as the table t1 was dropped and recreated again.

Is there any way I can recompile the stored procedure - so that the object becomes valid?

I don't want to alter and recreate the stored procedure, as there is no change in the definition.

Comment: What about the documentation on the subject, [Recompile a Stored Procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/recompile-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver16), didn't you understand?

Comment: Also, you've tagged *both* SQL Server 2008 and 2012 here. Are you really using *both*? **Both** of them are now **completely** supported as well, so you really should be finalising your upgrade paths (2008 has been completely unsupported for over 3 years now).

Comment: *"Now the tst_Proc will be in invalid state"* What do you mean by this as well? Even without recompilation, the procedure works fine both before and **after** you `DROP` and re`CREATE` the table: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kJ_MCEbs)